# MYSQL: select rows where a column contains a more string?

Tags: mysql

In my table, I have this situation:

```
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|  ID   |     CODE      |    VALUE     |   Etc... |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|   1   |    10a10a     | a1, b1, a2,  |          |
|       |               | c1, c5, e7   |          |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|   2   |    15cef1     | b1, n6, p1,  |          |
|       |               | y3, e7, d9   |          |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------+
|                                                 |
|                    Etc....                      |
```

When I run the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM code WHERE value IN ('10a10a') AND facilities LIKE ('%b1%')
```

I regularly get the response from the server. But, performing the query with `facilities LIKE ('%b1%', '%c5%')` the server returns no results.

What is the correct way to search for multiple values in the same column?

Comment: The _correct_ way would be to properly normalize this to begin with.

Comment: _“But, performing the query with facilities LIKE ('%b1%', '%c5%') the server returns no results”_ - I really don’t get how people always invent their own fantasy syntax in situations like this, and then wonder why it “doesn’t work” ... Did you read anywhere that LIKE could be used like that …? You want to join two single LIKE comparisons together with either AND or OR.

Answer (score 0):

You can query that with separate `OR` clauses.

`SELECT * FROM code WHERE value IN ('10a10a') AND (facilities LIKE ('%b1%') OR facilities LIKE ('%c5%'))`

Note the grouping of the OR statements surrounded by the extra brackets.

However, storing multiple values like that in the 'Value' column if you require to query on it, probably means the Value column should be normalised and moved to its own separate table, which you can then query using `JOIN` statements, and without the overhead of wildcard patterns using the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use or   when looking for 2 values in the like:

```
 WHERE facilities LIKE '1b1%' OR facilities LIKE '%c5%'
```